Python logging filter works with console but still writes to file
I am saving the logs to a text file and displaying them to the console at the same time. I would like to apply a filter on the logs, so that some logs neither make it to the text file nor the console output. However, with this code, the logs that I would like to filter out are still being saved to the text file. The filter only seems to work on the console output.
How can I apply the filter to the text file and the console output? Thank you very much
import logging

class applyFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return not record.getMessage().startswith('Hello')

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    filename='log_file.txt',
                    filemode='a')

console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.addFilter(applyFilter())
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
console.setFormatter(formatter)
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)

logging.info('Hello world')


basicConfig created a FileHandler and a StreamHandler was also created and added to the logger.  The filter was only applied to the StreamHandler.  To filter both handlers, add the filter to the logger instead:
import logging

class applyFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return not record.getMessage().startswith('Hello')

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    filename='log_file.txt',
                    filemode='a')

console = logging.StreamHandler()
# console.addFilter(applyFilter())  # not here
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
console.setFormatter(formatter)
logger = logging.getLogger('')
logger.addFilter(applyFilter())  # here
logger.addHandler(console)

logging.info('Hello world')
logging.info('world only')

Output (console):
2024-12-30 00:44:31,702 - INFO - world only

Output (log_file.txt):
2024-12-30 00:44:31,702 - INFO - world only


This worked perfectly, thank you very much!
